# Getting Custom Leaflet Search Control to getBounds on search selection

Tags: leaflet

So I have a this code below which isn't working unfortunately, I want the map to go to the selected marker when a user clicks on a item from the list.. Scroll down to where it says ItemSelected, The error I'm getting is that getBounds is not a function. Am I misusing this method or do I need to use a different method to get the map to pull up the selected marker?

```js
function sortBurearuIds(a, b) {
  var _a = a.feature.properties.bureauid;
  var _b = b.feature.properties.bureauid;
  if (_a < _b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (_a > _b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}




L.Control.Search = L.Control.extend({
 options:{
  //top right, topleft, bottom right, bottom left
  position: 'topleft',
  placeholder: 'Search...'
 },
 initialize: function (options){
  //constructor
  L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
 },
 onAdd: function (map) {
  // happenes after added to map
  var container = L.DomUtil.create('div','search-container');
  this.form = L.DomUtil.create('form', 'form', container);
  var group = L.DomUtil.create('div','form-group', this.form);
  this.input = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'form-control input-sm', group);
  this.input.type = 'text';
  this.input.placeholder = this.options.placeholder;
  this.results = L.DomUtil.create('div','list-group', group);
  L.DomEvent.addListener(this.input,'keyup',_.debounce(this.keyup,300), this);
  L.DomEvent.addListener(this.form,'submit', this.submit, this);
  L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
  return container;
 },
 onRemove: function (map){
  // when removed
  L.DomEvent.removeListener(this.input, 'keyup', this.keyup,this);
  L.DomEvent.removeListener(form,'submit', this.submit, this);
  
 },
 
 keyup: function (e) {
  if(e.keycode === 38 || e.keycode === 40){
   // do nothing
  } else {
   this.results.innerHTML = '';
   if(this.input.value.length > 2) {
    var value = this.input.value;
    var results = _.take(_.filter(this.options.data, function(x) {
     return x.feature.properties.bureauid.toUpperCase().indexOf(value.toUpperCase()) > - 1;
    }).sort(sortBurearuIds), 10 );
    _.map(results, function(x){
     var a = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'list-group-item');
     a.href = '';
     a.setAttribute('data-result-name', x.feature.properties.bureauid);
     a.innerHTML = x.feature.properties.bureauid;
     this.results.appendChild(a);
     L.DomEvent.addListener(a, 'click', this.itemSelected, this);
     return a;
    }, this);
   }
  }
 },
 itemSelected: function(e) {
  L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e);
  var elem = e.target;
  var value = elem.innerHTML;
  this.input.value = elem.getAttribute('data-result-name');
  var feature = _.find(this.options.data, function(x) {
    return x.feature.properties.bureauid === this.input.value;
  }, this);
  if (feature) {
    this._map.fitBounds(feature.getBounds());
  }
  this.results.innerHTML = '';
   },
 submit: function() {
  L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e);
 },
});

L.control.search = function (id, options) {
 return new L.Control.Search(id, options);
}
```

Comment: `fitBounds()` takes two opposite corners of a rectangle and adjusts the map so those corners fit on it. I can't quite work out what you want, but if it's to center the map based on a single marker, then you don't need `fitBounds()`, you probably need `map.panTo()` which takes a single lat/lng for the center.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to center to a single marker on the map, could I pass my feature variable to map.panTo() ?

Comment: So I actually passed feature._latlng as the argument and it worked. Thank you!